# Could not make a TCP connection to MacOS-BigSur TCP server

Tags: c#, macos, networking, .net-core, tcplistener

I am trying to establish a TCP Client-Server connection between my locally connected computers (MacBook-BigSur is the running server while a Windows 10 laptop is acting as a client). For this, I'm using Visual Studio Code to run both applications as follows:

On macOS:

```
Console.WriteLine("Starting build agent...");

var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 12345);
Console.WriteLine("Build agent Started ");
listener.Start();

while (true)
{
    var fileName = $"s-{DateTime.Now.Ticks}.tar.gz";
    using (var client = listener.AcceptTcpClient())
    using (var stream = client.GetStream())
    using (var output = File.Create(fileName))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Client connected. Starting to receive the file...");

        // read the file in chunks of 1KB
        var buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Client connected. File received successfuly.");

        Console.WriteLine(Execute($"tar -xvf '{fileName}'"));
    }

}
```

On Windows:

```
    var client = new TcpClient("192.168.0.109", 12345);
    Byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\shared\file.tar.gz");
    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    Console.WriteLine("data sent.");
```

However, when the Windows client is trying to establish the connection, it fails saying:

```
System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory.ExtendedSocketException: 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. 192.168.0.109:12345'
```

Note that after running the server I can see Visual Studio is using the port 12345 by checking it using `sudo lsof -i :123456` in Terminal. Besides, my Mac device is using the port `192.168.0.109`, the firewall is disabled and I can ping it using my Windows command prompt.

Comment: I don't know C#, but wouldn't `new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, 12345)` just listen on the loopback address only, not 192.168.0.109?

Comment: Thanks @GordonDavisson this was a copy-paste error. Actually, I'm using `IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1")` that listens to the localhost address, I updated the question details.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is localhost which means by definition the server is only reachable on the same host. If you want the server to listen on all interfaces don't specify an IP address or use `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: @Robert please post an answer to mark it as valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`127.0.0.1` is localhost which means by definition the server is only reachable on the same host.

If you want the server to listen on all interfaces don't specify `IPAddress.Any` respectively `IPAddress.IPv6Any` or use 0.0.0.0.